# wp.media.view.settings is empty when Forget About Shortcode Buttons plugin is enabled

Tags: wordpress

**Background**: One of my sites is using the Forget About Shortcode Buttons plugin, but this is throwing some sort of conflict since one of the recent Wordpress updates. I've been trying to contact the developer through Wordpress.org and Twitter, but to no success - they haven't replied to any support requests on Wordpress.org in months. I cannot remove this plugin because so many buttons on the site have already been created with it and I don't have the time to redo everything through a different plugin.

**Test Case**: The easiest way to see this is to simply download and activate the [plugin from here](https://wordpress.org/plugins/forget-about-shortcode-buttons/). Open up your javascript console and notice the error message 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined' and points to wp.media.view.settings.post.id being undefined as soon as you activate the plugin. When I go in and console.log wp.media.view.settings, that array is empty. So I think I've narrowed it down to there being a conflict with the plugin that prevents those settings from being set at some point.

Has anyone encountered this before and found a solution?